# Bootstrap alignment with columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap CSS framework and  have a row with 2 columns one with input field and label and other with input field with no label. Here it's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eh5yxsk/).

I want the second input field to be aligned with first input field. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" id="Last Name">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean horizontally aligned?

Comment: yes, it should be horizantally aligned

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7eh5yxsk/7/ is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-end">
          <input type="text" id="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>
     
</div>
```